# Components in module disappear when browser is resized (Flex 3)

Tags: browser, flex3, module, resize

We have this Flex app built on Builder 3 and we're using SuperTabNavigator from FlexLib to have some modules displayed. The thing is, whenever the user resizes the browser window all the contents on any tabs open simply disappear and there's no way to get them back. This only happens the first time, so if you close these 'broken' tabs and reopen them, you can resize all you want, but you still lost all you were doing in them and this is unacceptable. I've done some testing and found the module in that tab doesn't dispatch the resize events when this happens. It's dispatched when it opens (everything is set to 100% to fit the browser window, so it resizes on startup) and every other time you resize it without 'breaking' it. It gets weirder. I've also found that resizing works perfectly as long as you resize it to a size larger than the original (i.e. you open it in a browser window that is restored and then maximized), but even after doing that, if you change its size back to something even a pixel smaller than the original, the module just disappears. Everything else remains in perfect working conditions: any components outside tabs and the tabs itself work, but (summing up) anything within any tab open at the moment you first resize the browser window to a size smaller than the original just disappears.

I understand that this is a weird problem and hope some of you might be able to help me. Feel free to ask any questions if anything wasn't clear.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same problem with my application.  The issue stemmed from the fact that the RemovedFromStage event was being fired when the window was sized smaller than its original size.  I was catching the RemovedFromStage event and hiding my component, which resulted in this behavior.  A more detailed explanation can be found [here](http://jonathanbranam.net/flex3anatomy/class/Container/contentPane).